# how to create a list-view using angularjs?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

1. Display list of popular movies[10 title per page]
          URL : http://api.themoviedb.org/3/discover/movie?sort_by=popularity.desc
2. Display details of a movie on click data from previous GET could be used. 
         Fields should be mandatory : overview, release_date, vote_average

Any example code is there please share it to me. It will be helpful for me

Thanks in advanced

Comment: Are you building a jQuery page or an Angular page?

Answer (score 2):

Your question is a little bit vague but I can provide some information about ng-repeat.

In your controller, you could have an array like:

```
$scope.movies = [{title: "Avatar"}, {title: "Spectre"}, {title: "Teletubbies"}]
```

Then, in your HTML you could create a list like this:

```
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="movies in movies">{{movie.title}}</li>
</ul>
```

In the list item you can later add the ng-click attribute, the second part of your question. First, make sure to populate the list using the api!